# Automated way of subtracting height of specific starwars characters from other characters

Tags: r, tidyverse

Suppose I want to make a new column in the starwars dataset where I in an as automated way as possible subtract the height of Yoda from the height of Luke Skywalker, Anakin Skywalker, R5D4, and the height of R2-D2 from the height of Darth Vader, Leia Organa, Biggs Darklighter and the height of Gasgano from the height of Wilhuff Tarkin Chewbacca, Han Solo. How would I do it? I’m a newbie and I primarily use tidyverse. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for `outer`. I don't have the `starwars` dataset (is it in standard R?) but assuming it looks something like

```
name          height
Darth Vader   199
Yoda          72
...
```

Then

```
M <- outer(starwars$height,starwars$height,"-")
rownames(M) <- colnames(M) <- starwars$name
```

will give you a matrix with the height differences (the diagonals will be 0).

Comment: `starwars` is in `dplyr`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's a great solution

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't sure whether you were trying to automate only certain groups or have all the comparisons available (in which case you can pipe to get any potential grouping).  I love @JDL elegant matrix solution so I have taken it and just added a little like variable naming cleanup with `janitor` and some grouping

```r
library(tidyverse)
require(janitor)

M <- outer(starwars$height,
           starwars$height,
           "-")

rownames(M) <- colnames(M) <- starwars$name

new_starwars <- janitor::clean_names(as_tibble(cbind(starwars, M)))

# glimpse(new_starwars)

new_starwars %>% 
  mutate(heightminusYoda = yoda) %>%
  filter(name %in% c("Luke Skywalker", "Anakin Skywalker", "R5-D4")) %>%
  select(name, heightminusYoda)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   name             heightminusYoda
#>   <chr>                      <int>
#> 1 Luke Skywalker               106
#> 2 R5-D4                         31
#> 3 Anakin Skywalker             122
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot! This makes JDL's solution work really well for me!